# Change two separate SVG paths on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently experimenting with SVG paths in CSS. I currently have 2 separate SVG paths that on hover the CSS changes the SVG path.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.test{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:12;}

svg path {
  transition: d:0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: d 0.8s;
}


#l2:hover {
  transition: d 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: d 0.8s;
  d: path("M0,6.9c52.4,10.3,181,2.9,290.1,0");
}
#l1:hover {
  transition: d 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: d 0.8s;
  d: path("M0,6.9c53.1-9.8,184.8,4,290.1,0");
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 290.1 13.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 290.1 13.8;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="l1" class="st0" d="M0,6.9c98.8,0,191.3,0,290.1,0"/>
    </svg>

    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 290.1 13.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 290.1 13.8;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id='l2'  class="st0" d="M0,6.9c98.8,0,191.3,0,290.1,0"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="test">

    </div>
  </div>
```

**QUESTION**

Now I am looking to use the DIV element with the class "test" that when on hover targets and changes both the SVG paths. Is this possible to do this on CSS? If so how do I get the DIV to target and change both the SVG paths on hover?

Many Thanks

Louis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flexbox and the [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to be able to use the [`~` selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/g/general-sibling/) (or the [`+` selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/)) and to keep the same visual. You can also make both path inside the same svg so you can target them easily:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}

.st0 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 12;
}

svg path {
  transition: d:0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: d 0.8s;
}

.test:hover~svg #l2 {
  d: path("M0,6.9c52.4,10.3,181,2.9,290.1,0");
}

.test:hover~svg #l1 {
  d: path("M0,6.9c53.1-9.8,184.8,4,290.1,0");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">

  </div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 290.1 33.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 290.1 13.8;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="l1" class="st0" d="M0,6.9c98.8,0,191.3,0,290.1,0"/>
    <path id='l2' transform="translate(0,20)" class="st0" d="M0,6.9c98.8,0,191.3,0,290.1,0"/>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't work in Firefox.

I stumbled upon this question while searching an answer to my own ([Why doesn't Firefox show my SVG icons, and how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711083/why-doesnt-firefox-show-my-svg-icons-and-how-to-do-it)) so I thought I'd inform future users.