# Why doesn't Firefox show my SVG icons, and how to do it?

Tags: css, svg, firefox, css-variables

**Context**
I am creating a static website using HTML, CSS and JS only (for learning purposes). I successfully implemented two themes. In order to change it, I added an `SVG` icon in a `button` element. The svg then changes according to the theme (moon or sun).

**Problem**
While everything runs well in a chromium browser, the SVGs don't show at all using Firefox, but the buttons work as expected. I suspect this comes from the way I use CSS variables to change the `path` of the SVG on `hover`. However, using variables is quite the goal in my case.

**Outputs**
Here is the (expected) result I get in the chromium based browser:

[image: Chromium-based]

Here is the one I get in Firefox:

[image]

**Question**
How can I make the SVGs appear in Firefox using CSS variables ?

**MWE**
Here is an example. As you can see, in Firefox and unless the path is set inline as in the third svg icon, there is just nothing showing.

```css
:root {
  --square: "M 0 0 H 50 V 50 H 0 Z";
  --triangle: "M 0 0 V 50 H 50 Z";
  --color1: red;
  --color2: green;
  --color3: blue;
}


/*Doesn't work in FF*/
#path1 {
  d: path(var(--square));
}


/*Doesn't work in FF either*/
#path2 {
  d: path("M 25 0 L 50 25 L 25 50 L 0 25 Z");
}


/*Behaviour when hovered*/
#btn1:hover path {
  d: path(var(--triangle));
  fill: var(--color1);
}

#btn2:hover path {
  d: path(var(--triangle));
  fill: var(--color2);
}

#btn3:hover path {
  d: path(var(--triangle));
  fill: var(--color3);
}


/*Some more (off-topic) styling*/

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg {
  width: 25;
  height: 25;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">
  <svg>
    <path id="path1" />
  </svg>
</button>

<button id="btn2">
  <svg>
    <path id="path2" />
  </svg>
</button>

<button id="btn3">
  <svg>
    <path id="path3" d="M 0 0 H 50 V 50 Z";/>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: I think you'd need to convert from CSS variables to a SMIL based approach. That will work on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you elaborate ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **d** is an attribute, not a CSS property.
It is working in chromium browsers, as an experimental implementation.
But it was discussed and then rejected.

https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/49

https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/119

> "How can I make the SVGs appear in Firefox using CSS variable" ?

Assign the whole SVG as a CSS variable and put it as a "background" or "background-image".
You can save the whole SVG by encoding in base64 (bad practice) or use an URL encoder for SVG [like this one](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).

```
.bg {
  background: url(var(--yourCSSVar)); // or background-image even better
}
```

How to that:

SVG code (original):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FF00FF;}
</style>
<g>
    <rect x="3" y="3" class="st0" width="4" height="4"/>
    <path d="M6.5,3.5v3h-3v-3H6.5 M7.5,2.5h-5v5h5V2.5L7.5,2.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Copy your SVG code and google for a URL encoder for SVGs or a base64 encoder
(an example of [URL encoder](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/), an example of [base64 encoder](https://www.base64-image.de/)). Copy the output and you should have a string that looks like this one:

```
    "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 10 10' style='enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;'
xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:%23FF00FF;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect x='3' y='3'
class='st0' width='4' height='4'/%3E%3Cpath d='M6.5,3.5v3h-3v-3H6.5
M7.5,2.5h-5v5h5V2.5L7.5,2.5z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A"
```

Now, I will create a code snippet and use that string.

```css
:root {
--encodedSVG: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 10 10' style='enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:%23FF00FF;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect x='3' y='3' class='st0' width='4' height='4'/%3E%3Cpath d='M6.5,3.5v3h-3v-3H6.5 M7.5,2.5h-5v5h5V2.5L7.5,2.5z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
--svgOnHover: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 10 10' style='enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:%23FF00FF;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpolygon class='st0' points='3.95,6.08 1.54,5.71 3.28,3.92 2.88,1.44 5,2.61 7.12,1.44 6.72,3.92 8.46,5.71 6.05,6.08 5,8.32 '/%3E%3Cpath d='M6.46,2.37L6.26,3.6l-0.08,0.5l0.35,0.36l0.89,0.91L6.24,5.55L5.71,5.63L5.49,6.11L5,7.15L4.51,6.11L4.29,5.63L3.76,5.55 L2.57,5.37l0.89-0.91l0.35-0.36L3.74,3.6l-0.2-1.22l0.98,0.54L5,3.18l0.48-0.27L6.46,2.37 M7.78,0.5L5,2.04L2.22,0.5l0.53,3.26 L0.5,6.06l3.11,0.48L5,9.5l1.39-2.96L9.5,6.06L7.25,3.76L7.78,0.5L7.78,0.5z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.svg-background {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 2px solid;
  background-image: var(--encodedSVG);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.svg-background:hover {
  background-image: var(--svgOnHover);
}
```

```html
<h1> Example </h1>
<div class="svg-background"></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide me with an example ? I tried applying your technique but my attemps were unsuccessful. Thanks

Comment: That means that if I want to change the fill color on hover I need to hardcode it ? Because that would be a bummer if I want to use variables. Thanks anyways for the example !

Comment: if you need to do things with the SVG, I suggest simply put it inside the HTML. There is no reason to do everything with CSS variables when it's even counterproductive for you. That being said, you could simply change SVG on hover. There is no reason to just modify the original. There are a lot of things that have to match in order to be able to "switch/replace" some path tags inside of an SVG element (e.g viewbox of the SVGs).

Comment: added on hover example